# Kill user's session and logout through a interface menu

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

Can you advise me on how to kill somebody's session and make them logout from my MVC app.
My current plan is:

1. On the start of the app to load a SessionsCache
2. When user logins - save his session in tblSessions and partially reload the cache (add the session in it without making it call the DB)
3. Every 30 seconds an ajax will validate whether I have session or not
4. The administrator will have an interface tool containing all active sessions in the cache and when he kills a session he deletes it from the cache and DB
5. On the next ajax call the user wont have session and would be logouted
6. If a user logouts normally the session in the cache and DB will be deleted
7. Every 30minutes a full reload on the cache would be done

Please consider that my application has OnActionExecuting() overriden function which checks if the user has session and if not loggouts him.
But this happens only on action execution and if the user doesnt click anywhere (afk) he wouldn't be redirected to home page. (considering maybe the ajax call to check session is redundant?)

Also i want to clear user session when he closes the browser/tab without using the LogOut button but I am not sure how can this happen

Comment: In order for the client side to know if the session has expired ajax calls will have to be made to check for an active session.

Comment: Also to clear a session when the user closes the browser this too would have to involve polling.

Comment: @RyanSearle can you explain me what is polling or at least give me some link to where it is explained? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There's a few issues with your proposed solution that makes it unworkable:

1. Both sessions and auth employ client-side cookies to manage their status. The server can only invalidate the authentication/session. It cannot actually "log out" a user directly, because that piece is not under direct server-control. In other words, you can set up something that says that a particular user should be logged out, but that user will not actually *be* logged out until they attempt to make another request and some check is performed by the server which then affects that status change on the user at that time.
2. Sessions employ sliding timeouts. That means *any* request the client makes will reset the timeout of their session. In other words, if you long-poll the session status every 30 seconds, the user will effectively have a perpetual session that will never ever expire.
3. Sessions are intentionally anonymized. For security reasons, the client's only link to their session is the cookie with their session id. This prevents a certain level of session hijacking by making the cookie a must-have component in a successful attack. With things like the `Secure` token, then, and of course utilizing SSL on your site, you can effectively prevent that cookie from being usable in any other context than the client it was assigned to. The long and short is that there's not really any way to figure out which session belongs to a given user outside of direct contact with that user.
4. Cache is by nature volatile. You can say that particular key should have a lifetime of some period, but that's merely a suggestion. There's any number of different factors that could cause a cached item to be destroyed, most completely outside of your control.

Given all that that, you must approach this from a different direction. My suggestion would be to have a separate table where you track logins/sessions, in a generic sense. It would basically be a kind of log. When a user logs in or creates a new session, you would add a record to this database. If the user's auth or session expires, you would update the appropriate record. If the user deliberately logs out, you'd delete the record or otherwise mark it as inactive. As far as your admins go, they would then manage this table, removing or marking records as inactive.

Then, you will have to add some logic around your site actions to account for this table. You could create an action filter that checks this table and performs any necessary operations. For example, if the user has been "signed out" by an admin, the action filter would read the appropriate record from this table, see that the user had been signed out, and then affect that change by actually signing the user out.

Since long-polling will cause the session to never expire, you would essentially need to manage your own timeout. For example, you could record the time the session was created in the "log" table, and then compare that time with the current time on each subsequent request (including AJAX). Again, you could employ an action filter for this purpose. If the session is "expired" based on your timeout, then you could manually destroy the user's session.

There's plenty of other things you'd need to add or account for in this way, but hopefully that gives you a good framework to work from.